# Understand Crash Dump from Visual C++ App

Tags: c++, crash-dumps

**UPDATE**

Thanks to feedback below I was able to home in on ADPlus.vbs, which is part of the debugging tools for Windows.

Don't forget to set up _NT_SYMBOL_PATH before you run it.

Using this we've been able to see much more clearly in to the application with far greater clarity than we ever have using the regular dumps produced via Windows when the application crashes.

Many thanks to all for the responses.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

We have an server application written in Visual C++ that some times (relatively rarely) crashes on customer sites.  We haven't been able to understand why this happens based on looking at our own log files so the next step is to start looking at crash dumps.

We've just purposefully put a bug in to our app (a null pointer) so that we can generate a crash dump and verify that the dumps produced are valuable, but thus far I can't make head or tail of what i'm seeing.

I think my first question is whether i've even got WinDbg set up correctly (the other developer here is loading the dump in to Visual Studio 2010 and seeing the same errors so i'm assuming it's fine, or we're both wrong :) ) - and then next question is, how do I understand what it's telling me.

The main confusion is that the dump seems to be telling me it has reached a break point, which seems odd to me since there was no debugger connected.

The app was running on a Windows Server 2003 system when it crashed. I believe I have pointed WinDbg at the PDB file for the DLL and EXE correctly.

```
FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0
7c81a3e1 cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 7c81a3e1 (ntdll!DbgBreakPoint)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 8779fdb0
   Parameter[2]: 00000003

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

PROCESS_NAME:  CallPlusServerLauncher.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  8779fdb0

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  00000003

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[ffffffff]

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_BREAKPOINT

STACK_TEXT:  
1bd0ffc8 7c83fe08 00000005 00000004 00000001 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
1bd0fff4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x36


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0
7c81a3e1 cc              int     3

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ntdll

IMAGE_NAME:  ntdll.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  49900d60

STACK_COMMAND:  ddS 1bd10000 1bd0c000 ; dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ~439s; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  MANUAL_BREAKIN

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT_80000003_ntdll.dll!DbgBreakPoint

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:      http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/CallPlusServerLauncher_exe/0_0_0_0/4df87414/ntdll_dll/5_2_3790_4455/49900d60/80000003/0001a3e1.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbgBreakPoint -- Looks to me like you broke execution using a remote debugger.

If you didn't then I have seen DbgBreakPoint show up when you have code pages (Edit: I meant `page heap`) turned on (you should know if you did this) and there was a detection of invalid memory access.

Comment: Definitely wasn't caused by a remote debugger.  We're not aware we turned on code pages, no, however the detection of an invalid memory access presumably wouldn't be too far off the mark with a null pointer reference going on?  Is there a way to get the dump to give us a clue where the invalid memory access took place?

Comment: @Matt Peddlesden - Turn on code pages and run it with ADPlus.exe in crash mode. ADPlus should then generate a full dump when the invalid access takes place.

Comment: To be honest, not entirely sure what you're referring to with regard to "code pages" - isn't this about the character set?  E.g. 1250 is europe, 437 is US?

Comment: Sorry "page heap" not code pages! No wonder you were confused. Basically adds delimiting areas of known hex patterns to the start and end of allocated memory areas. Here check out these recourses http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286470 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. ADplus is part of debugging tools for windows, you should already have it given that you are using WinDBG.

Comment: Aha ok, yes i've found adplus - i'll go read up on page heap now, thanks Dennis!

Comment: Using ADPlus seems to be the best bet, it's pointed us straight to where our fake bug is, so we're going to go ahead along those lines.  Thanks for the help Dennis!

Comment: Good stuff. Hope it works out for you. Even using these tools might not uncover the root cause, it will only point you to the point where the bad memory would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Asserts can also trigger a breakpoint exception. For example I have (too often) seen them come out of the heap checking around a delete when the heap has got corrupted by double-delete or overflow. But only with the debug runtime I thought, is that what you have deployed?

Comment: For good or bad, there are no assert's in our code at least, and the "bug" we introduced was a simple null pointer problem.  Thanks for the feedback.